# SUDS - How to get a top level tag attribute

Tags: python-2.7, soap-client, suds

I have this structure in results of command test = client.service.XXX

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <n:StatusResponse xmlns:n="http://www.abcdefg/tatatata.xsd"
                      n:result="0">
      <n:Id />
      <n:SeqNo />
      <n:User />
      <Status>
        <n:Code>1</n:Code>
        <DevStatus n:devid="1"
                    n:val="0"
                    n:st="1000" />
        <DevStatus n:devid="2"
                    n:val="0"
                    n:st="1000" />
      </Status>
    </n:StatusResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If i set ON the log from logging

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

i found:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><n:StatusResponse xmlns:n="http://www.abcdefg/tatatata.xsd" n:result="0"><n:Id>1</n:Id><n:SeqNo>123456789</n:SeqNo><n:User></n:User><Status><n:Code>1</n:Code><DevStatus n:dev
id="1" n:val="0" n:st="1000"></DevStatus><DevStatus n:devid="2" n:val="0" n:st="1000"></DevStatus></Status><Cash n:type="1"></Cash><RequireVerifyInfos><RequireVerifyDenominationInfos><RequireVerifyDenomination n:devid="1" n:val="0"></RequireVerifyDenomination><RequireVerifyDenomination n:devid="2" n
:val="0"></RequireVerifyDenomination></RequireVerifyDenominationInfos><RequireVerifyCollectionContainerInfos><RequireVerifyCollectionContainer n:devid="1" n:val="0"></RequireVerifyCollectionContainer><RequireVerifyCollectionContainer n:devid="2" n:val="0"></RequireVerifyCollectionContainer></Require
VerifyCollectionContainerInfos><RequireVerifyMixStackerInfos><RequireVerifyMixStacker n:devid="1" n:val="0"></RequireVerifyMixStacker><RequireVerifyMixStacker n:devid="2" n:val="0"></RequireVerifyMixStacker></RequireVerifyMixStackerInfos></RequireVerifyInfos></n:StatusResponse></soapenv:Body></soape
nv:Envelope>
```

And i see:

```
<n:StatusResponse xmlns:n="http://www.abcdefg/tatatata.xsd" n:result="0">
```

How i get the vaule of result?

```
    <n:StatusResponse xmlns:n="http://www.abcdefg/tatatata.xsd"
                      n:result="0">
```

I have problem only on StatusResponse tag.

I take the elements of DevStatus tag normally but I can not take the elements of the tag StatusResponse . In the result of `print test` I not see tag StatusResponse

if i print results i see:

```
(reply){
   Id = None
   SeqNo = "123456789"
   User = None
   Status =
      (StatusType){
         Code = 1
         DevStatus[] =
            (DevStatusType){
               _val = 0
               _devid = 1
               _st = 1000
            },
            (DevStatusType){
               _val = 0
               _devid = 2
               _st = 1000
            },
      }
 }
```